# Clustering connected groups in Java

Tags: java, variables, cluster-analysis, relationship

I am very new to Java so I will start by apologizing for the lack of code to show. A while back, I had created a clustering program in both SQL (using cursor handling) and Python (using DataFrames) for Queue relationships and was asked to convert to Java - with no luck - so I hope someone has a good idea for how to do this.

This is the problem - using common variables of person and country:

I am trying to cluster every person who travels to a country and who have traveled to the same country so below you can see person A has traveled to Germany which person C has traveled to as well (so they should be in the cluster) Person A and B have both been in Sweden, B and C have been to the US etc., so they should be in the same cluster.  Person D and E have never been to the countries A, B, and C visited but they have both been to Iceland so they should be clustered.

[image]

So, the final solution would be something like this:

[image]

I should mention I know the steps to the problem but uncertain how to do this using arrays in Java – ***or if that is the best solution***.  This would be the steps as I see them:

1. make a unique list of countries
2. loop through countries (so selecting Germany first, as an example)
3. See all people who have traveled to Germany
4. Then, find all the other countries these people have traveled to
5. Then, looking at the new countries in 4, see if additional travelers not included before should be added
6. Then go through 4 and 5 until there are no additional people and countries and add a cluster number
7. Then, remove the countries in the first cluster from the list we had in step 1 and do it over again until there are no more countries in step 1

But doing this with arrays/lists rather than tables and frames is what I have not found a solution for …

Comment: Create a graph with people and countries as vertices and find all the **connected subgraphs**. Google for it, it's a basic graph theory problem.